# Atribuindo valores a variaveis dinamicas

Tags: python, variáveis

Estou tentando escrever um código que baixe a serie histórica de preços de ações do *yahoo finance*, depois preciso separar os dados. Quero que cada variável receba o nome da ação.

Por exemplo: Estou baixando os dados da Petrobras, então queria que ficasse assim: Volume_PETR4, Minimo_PETR4 e etc..
Porem não estou conseguindo atribuir os valores a essas variáveis, aqui esta o que fiz ate agora.

```
def desmenbrando_dados(acao,date1,date2, nome):
    pegando_acoes(acao,date1,date2,nome)
    globals()['volume_%s' % nome] = []
    globals()['minimo_%s' % nome] = []
    globals()['maximo_%s' % nome] = []
    globals()['abertura_%s' % nome] = []
    globals()['fechamento_%s' % nome] = []
    globals()['volume_teste'] = []
    for i in serie:
        vol = int(i['Volume'])
        volume_%s.append(vol) 
        maxi = float(i['High'])
        maximo_%s.append(maxi)
        mini = float(i['Low'])
        minimo_%s.append(mini)
        openn = float(i['Open'])
        abertura_%s.append(openn)
        close = float(i['Close']) 
        fechamento_%s.append(close)
```

Comment: Creio que não podes usar o caracter "%" numa variável.

Comment: existe alguma necessidade em fazer desse jeito? Recomendo que crie uma classe ou até mesmo um dicionário para lidar com isso.

Comment: @jsbueno muito obrigado pela ajuda, vc n so me respondeu a minha duvida como tambem me deu ideias melhores

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em Python, a separação de o que é dado (strings de texto, por exemplo) e o que é código é bem rígida - o que a diferencia de PHP, Perl e Shel Script.

Então, você pode criar nomes dinâmicos de variáveis, como faz - mas perceba que o nome é passado em uma string:
`globals()['volume_%s' % nome] = []` (O operador `%` com duas strings cria uma outra string que é usada como chave no dicionário global)

Assim `volume_%s.append(vol)` é simplesmente errado. Por coincidência não chega a ser um erro de sintaxe: a linguagem vai tentar usar o operador `%` com as variáveis `volume_` e `s`, e você deve ver um `NameError` (por que a variável `volume_` sem nada não existe).

Então, para fazer funcionar o que você quer, seria só acessar as variáveis da mesma forma que você as criou, como chaves no dicionário global. Para Não ter que ficar repetindo `globals()` em cada linha, você pode atribuir esse dicionário a uma variável curta:

```
g =  globals()
g['volume_%s' % nome] = []
...
for i in serie:
    g['volume_%s'% nome].append(int(i['Volume']))
```

E essa é a resposta para a sua pergunta.
Agora um conselho de boas práticas, que deve ter se tornado bem visível a essa altura: Você deveria usar variáveis para nomes que você conhece quando está codificando e tem função fixa - e usar dicionários para nomes que vai receber dinamicamente.

Nesse caso, por exemplo, você não ganha nada em guardar os seus dados no dicionário global (o dicionário que é retornado por `globals()`)  e um dicionário qualquer que você mesmo crie. (Na verdade, você ganha sim: a chance de sobre-escrever alguma outra variável de forma inesperada com as escritas diretas em `globals()` e ter um bug bem difícil de depurar).

COm um dicionário 'comum" você pode até guardar todos os seus dados num dicionário em que haja uma chavepara cada nome, e fica mais fácil visualizar e ver seus dados: e só adequar a visualizaçao (ou saida para arquivo) depois:

```
dados = {}
def desmenbrando_dados(acao,date1,date2, nome):
    dados_locais = dados[nome] = {}
    dados_locais['volume'] = []
    ...
    for i in serie: 
        vol = int(i['Volume'])
        dados_locais['volume'].append(vol)
```

Pronto - os dados de todas as séries estarão disponíveis no dicionário -este sim global - de nome fixo "dados". Melhor ainda, você pode fazer a função retornar o dicionário `dados_locais` e dispense o uso de `dados` global inteiramente: quem chama o `desmembrando_dados` se responsabiliza por consolidar o dicionário completo de cada empresa. Em suma, tem várias possibilidades - mas nenhuma em que você vá tirar algum benefício de criar os nomes das variáveis em si dinâmicamente - pelo simples fato de que iria ter que escrever o mesmo código de volta para ler os dados dessas variáveis dinâmicas.